# how to find XPath for complicated tag without id or name

Tags: xpath, selenium

I have to find out XPath for code :

```
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="redirectToUserList(5);" class="btnManage" value="Manage Users" style="background-color: transparent;">
```

Using firebug the XPath is :

> /html/body/div/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td
>   /table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/input

But how can I have a shorter XPath? For example, I wish the following could run:
//input[@value='Manage Users']

Please advise how to find shorter XPath using standard syntax?

Comment: Please, show the data so we can help you.

Comment: Using the XPath pseudo-operator `//` can be very inefficient (causes a complete traversal of the whole document tree), compared to using a specific path. Therefore, while possible, this isn't generally recommended.

Comment: "how can I have a shorter xpath like I wish following could run: //input[@value='Manage Users']" What makes you think that this XPath expression can't run? Did you try it and get an error? If so, what did the error message say? Did you get wrong results? If so, what were the results and how did they differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 6):

It is not mandatory to use id or name. You can use any attribute of that element.

Following are different xpaths for given locators

```
 1. "//input[@value='Manage Users']"
 2. "//input[contains(@onclick,'redirectToUserList')]"
 3. "//input[@type='button' and @class='btnManage']"
```

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to search for id or name, you can search for any attribute.

For example:

```
  //input[@value="Manage Users"]
```

which sounds unique

Answer (score 0):

As an addon to above given answers any specific attribute like id or name is never necessary.

We mostly take id and value to identify an element uniquely because other attributes may specify some other locators as well.

If any attribute is not creating confusion with some other locator you can choose it without any worry.

Lastly if you are not so good in writing xpath and also dont like large xpaths given by firebug just install an addon of firebug called as **Firepath** it will give you the shortest feasible xpath.

You can also go with other addons like Xpath Checker etc.